# How to publish bot from BotFramework to Teams?

Tags: botframework

I'm struggling through Microsoft's documentation on how to accomplish what should be a very simple task. I have created a bot on dev.botframework.com, tested it out via DM'ing my bot and creating code to handle certain responses, and now I'm ready to add it to channels, allow others to interact with it, etc.

To my understanding, I should be able to do this by either:

1. Uploading a custom app from within Teams
2. Publishing a bot according to the "Publish" tab in the Bot Framework
3. Submit the app to the IT team from within Teams

I'm not the Azure administrator, but my company's IT team is willing to allow me to create a bot - I just simply have to tell them what I need their permission to do, and I have no clue based on the three confusing options above.

My questions are:

1. How do I actually take the results of a bot on dev.botframework.com and make it available in the teams chat for everyone to use?
2. Does this actually cost *more* in any capacity?

In Slack, this was a very simple combination between 1 web hook and 1 event subscription (for mentions), but in Teams this seems a lot more complicated.

Comment: Have you had a chance to read these documentations? 1) [Connect a bot to Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). 2) [Distribute your Microsoft Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-publish-overview)

Comment: Also are you getting specific errors when publishing? if yes, could you copy and paste the logs of the errors?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @RamFattah turns out https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps is the place I need to be. I have no idea why the dev.botframework.com site exists. It seems pointless